# can concurrent hashmap handle up to 10000 threads without deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that spawns up to 10,000 threads. each of this threads would be updating a Hashmap. I know Hashmaps are not thread safe and hear concurrent hashmaps are thread safe. So can a cuncurrent hashmap handle this scenario with up to 10,000 threads updating it without a deadlock?

Comment: Is there some known deadlock bug in ConcurrentHashMap you're referring to?

Comment: Probably no reason to spawn 10,000 threads unless you are planning to use like a super computer haha, coming from java networking I could tell you it runs faster with a single thread rather then spawning a thread for each connection/client.

Comment: Do you really want 10000 threads? Each thread has its own stack and since stack's usual size is 1 MegaByte it seem the solution is not the best one.

Comment: And if there's high contention on the hashmap, you may spend all your time locking, even if you do somehow have 10,000 cores...

Answer (score 3):

Concurrent hashmap can handle an infinite number of threads without deadlocking.

However, why on earth do you want 10,000 threads sharing a map? There must be a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is your workload read or write-heavy? In the first case, `ConcurrentHashMap` will probably handle the load just fine, in fact most of the time it will be able to get the key without using any locking at all.

On the other hand, if your workload is write-heavy than it's very likely that you will incur in performance penalties due to the locking and you should probably start looking into alternative implementations, such as [Cliff Click's lock-free hashmap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/) (there's [a fork](https://github.com/boundary/high-scale-lib) on github that includes integration with maven) which is probably better suited for this kind of workload.